# How do you _unset_ the default printer?

Tags: macos, printing

I know I'm going to hit myself when someone tells me the answer, but I set the **Default Printer** on my Mac, and wish I hadn't.  Previously, it would default to the last printer used, which was great.  Now I can't find a way to **unset** the default printer to get back to the **last printer used** state.

FWIW, I'm on a Mac OS X 10.9.5 - Mavericks.

Command line solutions welcome too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **System Preferences** → **Printers & Scanners** and set **Default printer** to **Last printer used**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I knew I would hit myself, but I Just found my answer.  It's right there in the preferences dialog near the bottom.  I was too focused on the list of printers on the left.  Will delete my own question in just a second.

Comment: fair enough - just embarrassed that I asked such a silly question.